# Visual Studio installer 15.8.28010.2036 stalls at 97.55%

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I started the Visual Studio 15.8.5 offline layout with the command, where `exe` is the path to the installer and `install_path` is the install path:

`%exe% update --installPath %install_path% --quiet --wait --norestart --noWeb`

And it is stalling at 97.55% with two `vs_emulatorsetup` processes running.

`Layout progress: 97.55%
Download of 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/10629668/d68d54e233c956ff79799fdf63753c54/vs_emulatorsetup.exe' succeeded using engine 'WebClient'
Running 'D:\vs2017\enterprise\15.8.28010.2036\install\vs.emulator.android.bundle,version=1.1.1207.2,chip=x64\vs_emulatorsetup.exe' with parameters: /quiet /layout "D:\vs2017\enterprise\15.8.28010.2036\install\vs.emulator.android.bundle,version=1.1.1207.2,chip=x64"`

Downloading the offline layout has not been a problem for me before this point.

Comment: Questions like this need to document the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: To clarify, I am using the command ``%exe% --layout %layout_dir% --lang %lang% >offline_install.log`` from a batch file.

Comment: I have never had a problem with any anti-malware or other protections I may be running.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it just takes a long time for those bits to download. I mean a really long time. Some additional progress indication would be nice however.